# How to create a inner radius

Tags: flutter

How to create a inner radius in the appbar in Flutter. Please check the image.

[image]

Comment: Present your best effort, so that people can reproduce your effort easily, and what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a stack of widgets with a border radius in the top widget. You can use `Stack()` widget to achieve the UI

You can follow:

- Scaffold

  - Body

    - Stack

      - Widget 1
      - Widget 2

Answer (score 0):

you can make it by using **Transform.translate** in this way:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(0, -10)
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circle(15))
          child: ...
        )
      )
    ]
  )
)
```